# What is PurpleEventCallback?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, stack-trace

In the stack trace of my iPhone application, I see a call to something called `PurpleEventCallback`. I wasn't able to find any documentation for it. What is this?

[image: PurpleEventCallback]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Project Purple was the codename for iOS back when it was basically a skunkworks project within Apple.  This callback is basically just an event bridge between the `CoreFoundation` layer (ported from OS X) and the `UIKit` layer (the next-generation Cocoa framework).

- ["How Project Purple Turned into the iPhone"](http://allthingsd.com/20120803/apples-scott-forstall-on-how-project-purple-turned-into-the-iphone/)

Answer (score 8):

Just one more piece of information on PurpleEventCallback.

It's part of Graphics Services. In the case, if you disassemble GraphicsServices framework, you will find the source code of this method.